# Store LDAP connection and bind in session

Tags: php, ldap, session-variables

I've written an application where users are authenticated and logged in through LDAP. This works really well, I just do an `ldap_bind()` with their credentials, and if it's true then authenticate them - otherwise, tell them to sling it. I can keep their username in a session variable so I know who they are.

Now, a part of the application requires the users to search LDAP to find other users. I've used [`jquery-autocomplete`](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/) and [`ldap_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php) to implement this, and it works really well - users just type in the username, first name or surname, and all the possible matches are suggested. Lovely :)

However, corporate IT does not even allow anonymous browsing of the directory within the network, so, right now, I'm storing the username and password in `$_SESSION` so that I can do a new bind each time the autocomplete script is called.  I know it's *fairly* secure, and the tool is only internal, but this feels like something I shouldn't really do, and definitely wouldn't do if it was being let "out into the wild".

What I'd like to do is create the bind to LDAP when they log in, and then somehow have this authentication remembered across the session, so we can do as many searches as we need to without having to re-authenticate each time. I've got no access to the server, so I can't change anything on there. Can I somehow store the successful bind in `$_SESSION` and reuse it?

If this isn't relatively straightforward, does anyone have any other suggestions as to how this could be implemented?

Comment: Security note: `ldap_bind()` returns `true` if the password is empty and your LDAP server is configured to accept anonymous authentication. So make sure you escape special characters and then check for `length > 0`.

Comment: @Morris Fauntleroy were you able to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialize a resource-type (which is what the ldap_connect() returns).

What we have done in similar occasions, is to use a specific LDAP account that only has searching privileges on the LDAP tree (and specific type of data, like name,last name, email) and nothing else. This user's account credentials are stored in the database.

Perhaps to apply a 2nd level of security, you could allow this user to only connect from a specific IP (I think LDAP servers support this but I'm not 100% sure). So even if credentials are compromised, they are practically useless

Comment: Could you perhaps even throttle this dedicated user to prevent DOS attacks?

Comment: @Will, that would surely be advisable, especially if linking to a specific IP is not possible, good point.

Answer (score 0):

- The initial connection to an LDAP-compliant server is anonymous
- A successful BIND request changes the authentication state of the connection
- An unsuccessful BIND request (or a BIND request with zero-length DN and password) resets the authentication state to anonymous.

Therefore, once the connection is authenticated, and until a successful BIND request is processed, the connection retains its authentication state. This means the connection can be left open and operations transmitted on the connection the until connection is closed by the server or the client.

Note that an LDAP-compliant server has the option of sending a unsolicited notification that is not a response to a client request. Modern, professional-quality servers will use this mechanism to inform clients that a connection is being closed by the server for whatever reason.

In short, leave the connection up and keep using it. Better still, establish an authentication pool of connections to the server.

Update:

A connection to an LDAP-compliant server can remain open and can be used for as many transactions (request-response pairs) as the client desires (and the server permits). LDAP permits multiple transactions per connection, and also permits asynchronous connections.